# Process Builder - Base on Date Ranges

Tags: process-builder

I'm trying to use Process Builder to populate a client status one year ago today. We have a date field that I can base this on of, let's say, "Last Purchase Date". If this date field is between 12-18 months ago, I want to populate the status field with a given value.

I've tried using the conditions below, but it doesn't work. Any thoughts on what is wrong with this logic? I've been unable to get a good solution from Salesforce support.

[image]

Comment: PB only triggers when a record is created or modified. You'll need to take a different approach in order to make this work, perhaps a formula or something.

Comment: We have a sync process from external systems that "modifies" our records at least daily. I'm also testing the logic by modifying and saving records, and it's failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is inverted; it should be "less than" for the first entry, "greater than" for the second. To see why, consider this:

365 days ago was March 7th, 2018, so the first entry matches March 8th, 2018, but not March 6th, 2018. 545 days ago is September 17th, 2017. This means the second criteria will match September 16th, 2017, but not September 18th, 2017.

In computer logic, March 4th is *less than* March 5th, and March 5th is *greater than* March 4th. This is different than what we typically mean when speak about times in the past (e.g. in normal English, when we say "less than 5 days ago", it implies "after March 2nd").

Your combined logic looks like this to Salesforce:

```
  <--------------|        |------------>
     Less than 545        Greater than 365
```

At no point do they overlap. You'll need to invert the logic.

```
     |-----------------><---------------|
     Greater than 545       Less than 365
```